# Python: passing an optional named variable with *args **kwargs

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a custom dict class (`collections.MutablMapping`),the actual object is somewhat more complicated, but the question I have is rather simple, how can I pass custom parameters into the `__init__` method outside of `*args` `**kwargs` that go to `dict()`

```
class TestDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.store = dict()
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs)) 
        self.custom_name = None #how to pass custom name outside of the dict args? 
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.store[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.store[key] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.store[key]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.store)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)
    def __repr__(self): 
        return str(self.store)
```

Edit: (the code for my comment, again not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, especially if one had multiple keyname arguments to put into self rather than dict() ):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    try: custom_name = kwargs.pop('custom_name')
    except: custom_name = None
    self.store = dict()
    self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs)) 
    self.custom_name = custom_name
```

Comment: You mean like `__init__(self, custom_name, *args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: like __init__(self, custom_name=None, *args, **kwargs) except you can't have a defined name before default arguments. I was thinking of checking whether say 'custom_name' is in **kwargs, and if it is deleting it from kwargs that is passed to dict, else setting custom_name to None. Wondering if there is a standard way of doing this.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, you'd do:

```
def __init__(self, *args, custom_name=None, **kwargs):
    self.custom_name = custom_name

    # do your stuff...
```

In Python 2, you'd do:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.custom_name = kwargs["custom_name"]
        del kwargs["custom_name"]
    except:
        self.custom_name = None

    # do your stuff...
```

Either version will be instantiated like so:

```
d = TestDict({"spam": "egg"}, custom_name="my_custom_dict")
```

Comment: Yeah I did the same thing as you did for the python2 approach - didn't know you could do custom_name = None after *args before **kwargs in python3 though, will switch to that, thanks.